# Separating elements returned by xpath with commas

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple function returning the contents of a table retrieved via xpath from a website:

```
import traceback
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType



def get_hotbird_13e():


    # Downloads an up to date channel/country map for Hotbird 13e.

    try:

        chrome_options = Options()  
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("http://www.eutelsat.com/deploy_tvLineUp/struts/advancedSearch.do?orbitalPositionId=13%B0%20EAST&Langue=EN")

        link_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/table'
        link_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath(link_xpath).text

        driver.quit()

        print(link_path)


    except Exception as exc:

        print(traceback.format_exc())


get_hotbird_13e()
```

...this however returns all elements of the table in xpath with space used a separator. As some of the field values have spaces in them I cannot access the field values individually.

What do I need to amend in my code so that an example output of:

```
TVN TURBO TVN 13° EAST HOTBIRD 13C POLISH HD CONAX / IRDETO / MEDIAGUARD / NAGRAVISION / VIACCESS
```

...becomes:

```
TVN TURBO, TVN, 13° EAST, HOTBIRD 13C, POLISH, HD, CONAX / IRDETO / MEDIAGUARD / NAGRAVISION / VIACCESS
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the data row wise and then get all columns value in list and then join with ","

**Code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://www.eutelsat.com/deploy_tvLineUp/struts/advancedSearch.do?orbitalPositionId=13%B0%20EAST&Langue=EN")
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".listresult")))

for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='listresult']//tr")[1:]:
    rowwisedata=[td.text.strip() for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td") if td.text!=""]
    print(','.join(rowwisedata))
```

**Output**:

```
112 UKRAÏNA,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,UKRAINIAN,HD,CLEAR
13 ULICA,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,HD,CONAX / IRDETO / MEDIAGUARD / NAGRAVISION / VIACCESS
20 MEDIASET,Mediaset,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,ITALIAN,SD,NAGRAVISION / VIDEOGUARD
20 MEDIASET,Mediaset,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13E,ITALIAN,HD,NAGRAVISION / VIDEOGUARD
2M MONDE,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13B,ARABIC,SD,CLEAR,GENERAL
2M MONDE,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,ARABIC,SD,CLEAR,GENERAL
4 FUN DANCE,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC
4 FUN GOLD,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC
4 FUN TV,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC
6TER,Bis TV,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13B,FRENCH,SD,VIACCESS

And so on....
```

Comment: Glad it helps to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: @gdogg371 : Since the page is static you can use pandas data frame and load data into csv.If you need it let me know.I will update with that you don't need selenium in this case and very fast as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you like to get each cell within the table seperated, you have to use an xpath pointing to each cell. try this approach,

```
link_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/table//tr/td'
cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(link_xpath)
for cell in cells:
    print(cell.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
contents=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='listresult']//tr[*]")))
for item in contents:
    print item.text
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 one liner solution :

```
tokenize(replace(replace(substring-after(normalize-space(string-join(//tr//text()[normalize-space()]|//tr[@class]/@class,",")),",")," ?, ?",","),"oneven","even"),",even,")
```

Output :

```
String='112 UKRAÏNA,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,UKRAINIAN,HD,CLEAR'

String='13 ULICA,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,HD,CONAX / IRDETO / MEDIAGUARD / NAGRAVISION / VIACCESS'

String='20 MEDIASET,Mediaset,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,ITALIAN,SD,NAGRAVISION / VIDEOGUARD'

String='20 MEDIASET,Mediaset,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13E,ITALIAN,HD,NAGRAVISION / VIDEOGUARD'

String='2M MONDE,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13B,ARABIC,SD,CLEAR,GENERAL'

String='2M MONDE,Globecast,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,ARABIC,SD,CLEAR,GENERAL'

String='4 FUN DANCE,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC'

String='4 FUN GOLD,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC'

String='4 FUN TV,Cyfrowy Polsat,13° EAST,HOTBIRD 13C,POLISH,SD,CLEAR,MUSIC'

...
```